# Given the number of nodes, how can we find the total number of subgraphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, network

I am reading Uri Alon's "Intro to Systems Biology" where he introduces the concept of subgraphs in networks. He claims that with 3 nodes, you can make 13 subgraphs, with 4 nodes 199 subgraphs, and with 5 nodes 9364 subgraphs.

I have tried coming up with a formula for number of subgraphs given n nodes, and have scoured the internet but still have not found an answer. Any help is appreciated.

[image: The 13 subgraphs for 3 nodes]

Comment: This question relates for counting the number of non-isomorphic graphs on $n$ vertices. This is an open problem in mathematics, and was already discussed thoroughly here in several threads. For you question, every non-isomorphic graph produce several "subgraphs" (under your definition), by choosing the directions of the edges, but this of course depends on the number of the non-isomorphic nodes within the graph and the number of edges. To sum up, it's a highly non trivial combinatorics problem, which you'll get a lot of credit for solving :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A003085 but no closed-form formula is given, which is strong evidence that no closed-form formula is known, which may mean that no closed-form formula exists.

Comment: What is an explanation for why there is no closed-form formula? It seems like it should be a matter of combinatorics no?

Comment: Even the much simpler question of how many (isomorphism classes of) graphs there are with $n$ nodes has no known closed form. Ditto, the number of (isomorphism classes of) trees. To paraphrase Barbie, Combinatorics is hard!